# Embedded cdf files do not recognize presence of cdf player

Tags: cdf-format

When I run a html file with an embedded cdf file, I get the request that I should install cdf player.  Both my computers already have cdf player installed.  A specific example of this is in the file http://www.abstractmath.org/MM/Mathematica/RiemannSumExp.html

The code in the  was created by Mathematica 10.2.  I have posted many other html files that contain embedded cdf files which produce the same results.  They were made with previous versions of Mathematica.  A couple of them are

http://www.abstractmath.org/Word%20Press/?p=4532 (published in 2012)

http://www.abstractmath.org/Word%20Press/?p=2711 (2011)

All the files I published worked properly until about six months ago.

Comment: The first two links work for me (without a request to install the cdf player) but the third line (p=2711) just hangs with "Loading Computable Document Format..." for 5 cdf's.  (Windows 7, Internet Explorer, CDF Player 10.2).

Comment: I note that the source for the third link has "< ![CDATA[
// < ![CDATA[// < ![CDATA[" just before "var cdf = new cdfplugin();" where the other two do not.  I know very little about HTML but that is at least a difference among the three links.

Comment: That third source was produced by Word Press, which messes with code in a very annoying way.  Or it did three years ago, anyway.  I know how to fix that and I will.  But I still have the main problem: other people's computers run the cdf file but neither of my computers does (both are Windows 7).  Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

The reason the embedded CDF file is that embedded CDF files no longer work in Google Chrome.  I have switched to Firefox, and it works fine.  (Some older Gyre&Gimble files still have problems but I know how to fix them.)